# Parent pom version in child project pom

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have project 1, 2 and 3.

Project 2 and 3 uses project 1 version.

- Project 1 - Version 1.0,
- Project 2 uses Project 1 - version 1.0,
- Project 3 uses Project 1 - version 1.0

Every time I have to up-ref the version I have to change it in 3 places.

Is there a way I can give a relative version in project 2 and 3?

Comment: If by *Project 2 and 3 uses project 1* you mean project1 is a dependency in project2 and project3. You should maintain 3 difference files unless they are all under the same tree of some module.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.
Take a look at Maven Versions plugin at

[Maven Versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

It has a goal to update childrens' parent version 
[versions:update-parent](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html)

you will need to run that plugin's goal when you'd like to update parent version in children. It works perfect through deep multi-level hierarchy as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are few alternatives in order to keep transitive dependency versions aligned across multiple projects.

- Dependency version property propagation from parent POM

This is the most simplest option when you are working with somewhat flat project structure. Declaring project version property and keep it updated will help managing transitive dependency correctly.

- Use of Version dependency plugin

As Vadim suggested, you can choose to use versions [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/advancing-dependency-versions.html) to advance dependency version to appropriate version.

- Creation of BOM for transitive dependencies ( >= Maven 2.0.9 )

This option is most feasible if you are dealing with lot of transitive dependencies. Bill Of Material helps in declaring and maintaining dependency compatibility.